# Compute the inner product with an operator given by the tensor product of two tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, hadamard-test

Assume I have a quantum register made of $N$ qubits.

Assume I want to compute the inner product

$$
\langle  \psi|I_{n_y} \otimes  A_{n_x}| \psi \rangle . 
$$

Note that I am using statevetor simulations for the moment. Here, the state $\psi$ has dimension $2^N$, the identity matrix $I_{n_y}$ has a side of length $n_y$ and the matrix $A_{n_x}$ has a side of length $n_x$, with $2^N = n_x n_y$.
Assume that I have already the circuit computing

$$
\langle  \psi'|A_{n_x}|\psi' \rangle ,
$$

where $\psi'$ is a quantum register of $n_x$ qubits.

How do I compute $\langle  \psi|I_{n_y}\otimes  A_{n_x}|\psi \rangle $?

Extra: what about $\langle  \psi | A_{n_y} \otimes I_{n_x}|\psi \rangle $?

Comment: Are you asking mathematically how to compute this, or practically, e.g. on a quantum computer?

Comment: Practically on a quantum computer, assuming I have already a cirucuit which is able to compute the contribution of the matrix $A_{n_x}$ on a register with $n_x$ qubits.

Comment: Then why can't you do exactly the same circuit, and just add $\log_2n_y$ extra qubits, preparing the overall state in $|\psi\rangle$ and running the circuit you know on the $\log_2n_x$ qubits?

Comment: Oh so I basically can ignore the quantum register referring to the identity $I_{n_y}$ part? I was suspecting it but I was not 100% sure as I am still a beginner in quantum computing.